# Having Trouble with FileReader in Next.js 13 to Convert Image to File Data Format

Tags: next.js, django-rest-framework, next.js13

I am using the given lines of code in async function for post API in Next.js 13. For making a post request in Django REST framework. I am not able to give image input from frontend.

```
  const blobLike = image.blobLike.target;
  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = function(event) {
    const imageData = event.target.result; 
  };
  fileReader.readAsDataURL(blobLike);
  console.log(blobLike)
```

I want to convert image to Form Data format for Django REST framework.

Comment: Can you show how you are using the `imageData` as well, along the code shared in the question description?

Comment: const addProduct = async (FormData) => {
  "use server";
  const image = FormData.get("image")
 //Rest of the constants.
const rev = {
 name,description, seller, image,price,discount, customer_count, stock, category
 }
await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/products_list/', {
method: "POST",
body: JSON.stringify(rev),
headers:{
 "Content-Type": "application/json",
 }
})  
}
<form action={addProduct} className={styles.productForm}>
//Rest of the inputs
<label htmlFor="image">Image:</label>
<input type="file" id="image" name="image" accept="image/*" />
Submit button

Comment: Can you add all the code to the question description? Hard to read from a comment.